# How can I install Nachos?

Tags: 12.10

I'm trying to install Nachos on 12.10.  All methods I've tried failed -- I tried various ways, but unfortunately none of them worked.

I need to run the Nachos system to understand the nature of operating systems. Can any person help me to solve this installation problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The README is here: http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~tom/nachos/README.

It should explain how to install everything ;)

The directions might change, but now they include these steps:

> To get started, you should:
>
> 1. use ftp to fetch the nachos.tar.Z file (turning on binary mode first)
> 2. uncompress nachos.tar.Z
> 3. tar -xf nachos.tar
> 4. lpr paper.ps  -- print out the paper describing nachos
> 5. lpr doc/*.ps  -- print out the sample assignments
> 6. cd code; make print -- print out the nachos source code
> 7. cd code; edit Makefile.dep -- select host machine type
> 8. cd code; make all -- compile nachos source code
> 9. cd c++example; lpr *.ps *.h *.cc -- print out C++ primer

You won't have to use `lpr` -- you can print out documentation as you normally would under Ubuntu, or use `evince` or another program to view the .ps files.

The Wikipedia page on Nachos (or, [Not Another Completely Heuristic Operating System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Another_Completely_Heuristic_Operating_System))  may provide more context.

It mentions several successors to Nachos:

> As Nachos has not been in active development for a number of years,
>   and possesses a number of recognized flaws [...], successor projects
>   have been initiated. In 2004, Stanford University created Pintos, a
>   Nachos-inspired system written in C and designed to run on actual x86
>   hardware. In 2000, Dan Hettena at UC Berkeley ported Nachos to Java as
>   Nachos 5.0j, in an effort to make Nachos more portable, more
>   accessible to undergraduates, and less susceptible to subtle bugs
>   [...]. Another Java-based version was created by Professor Peter
>   Druschel at Rice University.

Comment: I know this but tell me where can I find an image "iso" for nachOS? to run it with virtualbox

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, NachOS is not an image or a complete operating system, it seems more like a course. The README should be able to help :) http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~tom/nachos/README

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help :). Just as a reminder, always read the README (I'm guilty of not doing that too, don't feel bad :P)